# Send a message to a specific user by its userName in SIgnalR Core

Tags: jwt, signalr, asp.net-identity, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I added SignalR Core to my Asp.net Core 3 Web Api project an this web api communicates with my Android application , I am trying to send message back and forth between two client , and I don't want to use the connection_Id because when a user leaves an activity where the connection is made, the connection is lost and the connection_Id will change if the client reconnects , and in that case the communication between the two users will be lost , and the second user will be unable to communicate with the first user because the other's connectionId has changed , so I want to use the userName or the userId to send messages between users

PS : When I send message to all clients , or with connectionId the code works fine.

PS : I am using identity and JWT to authenticate and authorize users in my app.So I have this method In my Hub :

```
public async Task sendOffer(DeliveryOffer offer)
        {

            string name= Context.User.Identity.Name;
            Notifications notification = new Notifications();
            notification.deliveryOffer = offer;
            await Clients.User(name).SendAsync("sendOfferToClient", notification);
        }
```

and this is mycustomerUserIdProvider :

```
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public virtual string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {

            return connection.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```

In my startup class inside the configure method I addded signalR after adding Authentication like below :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSignalR(routes => {
                routes.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/myHub");
            });
```

and inside my configureServices method :

```
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserProvider>();
```

But this instruction here always returns null:

```
string id = Context.User.Identity.Name; // Always null
```

And this is the method that generates the Token in my controller :

```
    private TokenResponse generateToken(User user)
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.Secret);
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud, user.Email),
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.UserName),
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.UserName),
                                }),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                };
    
                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    
                TokenResponse response = new TokenResponse();
                response.token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
                return response;
            }
```

This is my ConfigureServices method :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                JwtSettings jwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
                Http_Client http_client = new Http_Client();
                Configuration.Bind(nameof(jwtSettings), jwtSettings);
    
    
                services.AddIdentity<SuperUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AkdContext>()
                .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>();
                services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
                {
                    
                });
    
              
                services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
                services.AddAuthentication(x =>
                {
                    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
                    {
                        x.SaveToken = true;
                        
                        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Secret)),
                            ValidateIssuer = false,
                            ValidateAudience = false,
                            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                            ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                            RequireExpirationTime = false,
                            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            
                            
    
                        };
                        x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                        {
                            OnMessageReceived = context =>
                            {
                                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
    
                                // If the request is for our hub...
                                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                                    (path.StartsWithSegments("/myHub")))
                                {
                                    // Read the token out of the query string
                                    context.Token = accessToken;
                                }
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            }
                        };
    
                    });
    
                services.AddAuthorization();
    
                services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserProvider>();
                services.AddSignalR();
    
                services.AddMvc();
                services.AddDbContext<AkdContext>();
                
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddSingleton(jwtSettings);
                services.AddTransient<IHttp_Client, Http_Client>();
    
                //services.AddTransient<ICommandRepository, CommandRepository>();
                //services.AddTransient<ICommandService, CommandService>();
                
    
                services.AddTransient<IOrderRequestRepository, OrderRequestRepository>();
                services.AddTransient<IOrderRequestService, OrderRequestService>();
    
                services.AddTransient<INotificationRepository, NotificationRepository>();
                services.AddTransient<INotificationService, NotificationService>();
    
                
                services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
    
            }


and this is the Configure  method :

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {

                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSignalR(routes => {
                routes.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/myHub");
            });
           

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

        }
```

Comment: Did you try to get the user id like this: `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)`  ? then you fetch the user by injecting the `UserManager` in your hub

Comment: Also are you adding the username as a `Claim` when issuing tokens? something like this: `new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)`

Comment: Yes I added the userName as a Claim but I still get Null @HMZ

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? according to the docs there are some limitation in your approach and you have to append the access token to the query string manually see here [SignalR docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1) search for "OnMessageReceived".

Comment: Yes I followed the docs guidelines. @HMZ

Comment: is there a way to create constant connection_id to each client , in other words the server will generate the same connection_id for the  user A each time he connects ?

Comment: Of course not this won't be realistic at all, I don't see a reason why this won't work for you unless you have a misconfiguration somewhere else.

Comment: I updated my question and added the method that generates the JWT token for the user . @HMZ

Comment: Try this:  `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)`

Comment: it is always null @HMZ